# Image Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Tags: html, css, image

rodoweb.com/rajat is the name of my website. I have two console errors about my image paths, and I need help fixing them. I get a 404 (not found) error. The background image won't load, and an image on the side of my website won't load. Thank you for you help.
    
     Rajat Doshi

```
</head>

<body>
<div id="navigation">
        <a href="#splashScreen"><img src="images/vote_count.png"></a>
</div>

<div id="splashScreen">
</div>

<div id="splashScreenOverlayParent">
    <div id="splashScreenOverlayChild">
        <a href="#learn">Get Involved</a>
        <a href="#donate"> Canidates </a>
        <a href="#map"> 2016 </a>
    </div>

</div>

</body>

</html>

CSS

#splashScreen {
background-image:url(washington.jpg);       
position: relative;
display: table;
min-height: 100%;
height: auto;
width: 100%;
/* Code for full-page background */
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='http://media02.hongkiat.com/oversized-background-image-design/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale')";
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.http://media02.hongkiat.com/oversized-background-image-design/bg.jpg', sizingMethod='scale');
z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a directory listing?

Answer (score 2):

Two possible causes come to mind:

1. Are the files readable by the HTTP process? usually (assuming linux), you would have to do `chmod o+r *` on the files that need to be viewable. The images directory would need to be readable and executable `chmod o+rx images`.
2. Are they in the correct location?

Comment: First of all thanks @Nathan Webb. Second, where do I insert chmod o+r*. I am new to programming, so I am not sure what to do.

Comment: Also, I am able to see the photos on preview in chrome, but I can't see them online.

Comment: chmod is to change the permissions on the file, which you need to do on the command line... But that's assuming that you have access to the command line. If you don't (or don't know how to use it), then your host should have some way of managing files. What is the name of the host? Can you use cpanel to manage your website?